# Maximum number of points $k$ distance apart in a $k\times k$ square

Tags: geometry

How do I prove that a $k\times k$ square can fit at most 4 points that are at least $k$ distance apart?

Each point is at a corner of the square, and is the center of a circle with radius $\frac{k}{2}$. The area of a circle that is inside the square is $\frac{\pi k^2}{16}$. The total area of the square is $k^2$. Therefore, the square can have $\frac{16}{\pi} \sim 5.1$ points.

But that's not true, because putting another point won't satisfy the minimum distance constraint.

[image]

Comment: Notice the proper way to typeset $k\times k$. $\qquad$

Comment: @SimpleArt Mistake, thank you

Comment: You have shown that the square cannot have more than 5 points, but you have not shown that it can have 5.  In fact it cannot.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to prove that it can only have at most 4. Adding a point in the center, it's distance would only be $k\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$ from all the other points.

Comment: @QuaxtonHale That is the idea. However, you have to also rule out any other distribution. For instance, why can't there be some ugly, asymmetrical way of getting five points in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points in the same quadrant are at most $\frac k{\sqrt2}$ apart, and there are only four quadrants.